# Node js service that manages k8s jobs - is it feasible?

Tags: node.js, kubernetes

I need to create a node.js service that is supposed to run a large number (potentially hundreds) of scheduled jobs simultaneously. This service should also expose a REST interface to allow end users to perform CRUD on these jobs.
At first I thought of going for agenda.js and since we use k8s, launching a few instances so we could deal with this amount of jobs.
However, I also thought of another idea and wanted to see if somebody already done if - since we use k8s, I thought of harnessing the power of k8s jobs and create a service that will communicate with k8s api and manage the jobs.

Is it feasible? What things do I have to take into consideration if i'm going in this direction?

Comment: You can use the [Kubernetes API](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/kubernetes-api/) to create Jobs; but you need to keep track of what you've created and know how to recover even if your coordinator process fails.  A dedicated job queue like RabbitMQ is probably easier to manage and to work with in development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you want is basically the definition of kubernetes  [operator](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/extend-kubernetes/operator/), and yes, it is possible to do what you want.

in your case, you can use the kubernetes client for [nodejs](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/javascript)